# Crystal - method pointers

Tags: pointers, methods, crystal-lang

Is is possible to use method pointers in Crystal ?

And if yes, how do I create and use them ?

I wish to store multiple instructions in an array and then call the required one later in the programm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `Proc` is for.

```
def foo()
  puts "foo"
end

def bar()
  puts "bar"
end

procs = {->foo, ->bar}

procs.each do |p|
  p.call
end
```

outputs

```
foo
bar
```

See online: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/2vb7

It also works with methods and static methods:

```
class A
  def self.foo()
    puts "A.foo"
  end

  def bar()
    puts "bar"
  end
end

proc = ->A.foo

puts proc
proc.call

a = A.new

proc = ->a.bar
proc.call
```

Read more in the official docs: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/proc.html